# Magento 2: How to debug on Checkout Pages when having KnockOut JS & Web Template

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, knockoutjs, debug

http://localhost/magento2/checkout/

**vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\Hostedpro\Request.php**

```
public function setPaymentMethod($paymentMethod)
    {
        $this->paymentMethod = $paymentMethod;
        $requestData = $this->getPaymentData($paymentMethod);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($requestData);
        exit;

        $this->addData($requestData);

        return $this;
    }
```

I'm not able to see on FireBug or it's neither printing on browser or neither in View Source.

Checkout page just shows Blank.

On any of the checkout pages, when you have combination of KnockOut & Web Template

Example: **vendor\magento\module-paypal\view\frontend\web\template\payment\paypal-express-in-context.html**

Whenever you do PHP `echo` or Javascript `alert` it's not gonna work. So how to check & debug?

Must say for me it's tough for now & time-consuming. In CorePHP can do easily but Magento 2 + Zend + KnockOut +++.

Comment: Have you checked all request inside console? some of the request is break and inside this request your data is display.

Comment: Already checked. Not breaking anything.

Comment: in the chrome, use `Inspect` and then in the `Source` tab select your file(ex. js or html) then `Breakpoints` lines you need, Refresh the page and it will stop at breakpoints and display results

Comment: You should use Xdebug for debugging PHP applications. It will make your job SO much easier.